# Removing unchecked checkbox from final code in JS

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I creating a HTML generator, I've used checkbox in the form.

In the resulting code, I'm getting the unchecked boxes as ''.

I have the current code setup at http://jsfiddle.net/Rqe6K/ for your review.

How can the final result be achieved so that only the checked box values are part of the text?

`<button onclick="toggle('answer','1','','3','')">Click</button>` from this the blank space of the respective checkboxes should be removed.

```
<form id="band" action="#">
  <label>Option 1: <input type="text" id="a1o1"><input type="checkbox" id="a1" class="can"></label><br>
  <label>Option 2: <input type="text" id="a1o2"><input type="checkbox" id="a2"  class="can"></label><br> 
  <label>Option 3: <input type="text" id="a1o3"> <input type="checkbox" id="a3"  class="can"></label><br> 
  <label>Option 4: <input type="text" id="a1o4"><input type="checkbox" id="a4"  class="can"></label><br> 
  <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
<p>Copy this:</p>
<textarea rows="20" cols="80" id="code"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('band').onsubmit = function() {
      box1 = '';
      box2 = '';
      box3 = '';
      box4 = '';
      if (document.getElementById('a1').checked) { box1 = '1'; }
      if (document.getElementById('a2').checked) { box2 = '2'; }
      if (document.getElementById('a3').checked) { box3 = '3';  }
      if (document.getElementById('a4').checked) { box4 = '4'; }
      var text="<button onclick=\"toggle(\'answer\',\'"+box1+"'\,\'"+box2+"'\,\'"+box3+"'\,\'"+box4+"'\)\">Click</button>";
      document.getElementById('code').value=text;
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The result you want then is that `<button onclick="toggle('answer','1','3')">Click</button>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put an ID called `a1o1` but then try to find it using `a1`, it is normal that the browser never find the control.

**UPDATE**

Not very cool, but works...

http://jsfiddle.net/A6f9r/

**UPDATE2**

http://jsfiddle.net/v7rfN/

Comment: Thanks @adripancio this helps, I have another issue. Is there a way for the toggle function name to change for example `toggle1('answer','1')`  and `toggle2('answer','1','2')` based on the number of checked boxes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare the variables instead of making it global.
i.e. `var box1='';`

Use this logic-

```
var text="<button onclick=\"toggle(\'answer\',\'";
    if(box1!='')
    {
        text+=box1+"'\,\'";
    }
    if(box2!='')
    {
        text+=box2+"'\,\'";
    }
    if(box3!='')
    {
        text+=box3+"'\,\'";
    }
    if(box4!='')
    {
        text+=box4+"'\)\'";
    }
   text = text.substring(0, text.length - 2);
    text+=")\">Click</button>";
```

See fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/Rqe6K/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery I warmly suggest it, since its syntax is concise:

```
$("#sendAnswer").click(function(){
    var answers = $("input[name='answer[]']").map(function(){if(this.checked){return this.id;}}).get();
    var text = "<button onclick=\"toggle(\'answer\'," + serializeInputValues(answers) + ")\">Click</button>";
    $('#code').val(text);
    return false;
})

function serializeInputValues(fields){ 
    var sStr = "";
    jQuery.each(fields, function(i, field){
        sStr += "'" + field + "', ";
    });

    return sStr.slice(0, -2);
}
```

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUG9t/).

**EDIT**: With this approach, your answer can grows and your code still remain the same, with your approach you have to add an `if` for each new checkbox driving you to a potential combinatorial explosion.